# How to see the effect of a query that does not return results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Some queries return no results, but a message

> command(s) completed successfully

is returned after they are executed. How do I find out the effect the query has had on the database (if any) ?

Comment: I'm not clear on what information you want to obtain. Could you maybe give an example?

Comment: @vikas - that is the opposite of what I want to do. It does not work

Comment: Do you want to check how many rows were affected by your query??

Comment: @NetStarter - yes, and if possible i want to see the result in "before" and "after" format. Are there any SQL queries that never affect any rows ?

Comment: USe @@RowCount to check how many rows were affected and Print them before and after

Comment: `UPDATE TableX SET X = Y WHERE 1 = 0` is a query that does not affect any rows.

Comment: @NetStarter - i get an error incorrect syntax when I use "@@RowCount" and execute it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Is it possible that a much bigger query can have no effect on a DB ? i am not considering a query where the WHERE clause is not satisfied.

Comment: Any query with a `WHERE` clause or with `JOIN`s in the `FROM` clause can potentially be reduced down to a set of zero rows for the actual manipulation.

Comment: The @@RowCount returns the number of rows affected by the query http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx but @Damien_The_Unbeliever point is a valid one the query does not affects any rows > UPDATE TableX SET X = Y WHERE 1 = 0

Answer (score 2):

Usually, it is only DDL queries that just return

```
command(s) completed successfully
```

For example if you create a table/view/sproc/function or any other object in the DB, you will only get the above statement.

When you are executing DML, then you should ideally get

```
(xxx row(s) affected)
```

Even with an unsatisfied WHERE clause, you will still get

```
(0 row(s) affected)
```

Unless, of course you first executed

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

which incidentally when executed on its own will give

```
command(s) completed successfully
```

Why don't you just post your query here, so we know what you are talking about?

Raj

Comment: yes, i was making a function. Unfortunately, I deleted the query. I want to see if the function would work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to see before and after values you need to write them in to the statements yourself. You could also do multiple print statements to see what has happened (you have to create them.)

One word of caution - if you are using something like VB/C# to get the results, remember that any select results will be returned from a stored proc. So if you did a select before the changes, made changes and then did a select again, the new records would be in the second table.

Typically if I'm doing an update to a record in a stored proc, if it would not normally return anything I will return all the records that were changed. Then if somebody calls the proc but ignores the results, no harm is done.